# c - openGL glDrawPixels

Tags: c, opengl

I'm new to graphics programming. I'm trying to draw using glDrawPixels but my program doesn't have any outputs. 
I researched online and I keep on getting different answers on what data I should pass into glDrawPixels.
I have seen `data[w*h*3]`, `data[w*h][3]`, and `data[w][h][3]` which is the best?

So far, 
I'm storing my RGB values under the display function:

```
float pixels[1024][768][3];
int i,j;

//Should give me all red
for (i = 0; i < 768; i++) { 
  for (j = 0; j < 1024; j++) { 
     pixels[j][i][0] = 255.0;
     pixels[j][i][1] = 0.0;
     pixels[j][i][2] = 0.0;
  }
}
glDrawPixels(1024,768,GL_RGB,GL_FLOAT,pixels);
```

my main program:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize (1024, 768);
    glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0; 
}
```

The output I got is just an empty window, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify where you would like the pixels to be placed within the *viewport* (which is the same as your window, given what you've provided).

Try calling `glWindowPos2i(0, 0)` before you're `glDrawPixels` call.  This should position what's called the *raster position* at the lower-left corner of your window.

As to your question about the best way to declare your pixels, any of the forms you suggest are sufficient, given they create a contagious array of memory for storing your pixel data.  The differing number of dimensions on the array you declare only affects how you index into the array.

Comment: unfortunately, adding glWindowPos2i(0,0) before glDrawPixels does not work. my window is still blank (white)

Comment: First, are you swapping your buffers after rendering?  That is, since you specified `GLUT_DOUBLE` in your `glutInitDisplayMode` line, you need to swap buffers at the end of rendering by calling `glutSwapBuffers`.  Also, if you're using `GL_FLOAT` as the type for `glDrawPixels`, the maximum color value is 1.0.  Not a problem here; just that you're values will be clamped to 1.0.

Comment: What will be the best type for the data? also, do you mean that if I want red, it will be rgb(1 0 0)?

Comment: Use the type that's most convenient to you.  What's important is that the maximum pixel value is related to the pixel's type.  For float, for example, the maximum pixel value is 1.0.  If the type is say GLubyte (which is unsigned char in C parlance), the value is 255.  Basically, unsigned integer types use their maximum value as maximum color intensity.  For floating-point types, the max value is 1.0.  So for your example, (1, 0, 0) as floats is the right pixel value.

Comment: Actually, you want to call `glutSwapBuffers` after all of your rendering in your `display` function (like the last function call before `display` returns)

Comment: I just want to throw in, that you should not use `glDrawPixels` at all. It's a rather slow function and has been removed from modern OpenGL. If you want to draw pixels to the screen you should load the image into a texture and either draw a textured quad (or with modern OpenGL bind it to a FBO and perform a glBlitFramebuffer).

Comment: Without in any way trying to provoke a religious war (which I'm sure will happen regardless :-), since the OP is using GLUT, they're automatically using a compatibility profile, and while all of your points are relevant, `glDrawPixels` is the simplest way to get pixels to the screen using GL.  I firmly believe that things like compatibility profile have a place in simplifying learning how to use GL.  We can discuss the merits of doing it "right" from the get-go, but there's a great joy in making two function calls, and seeing something on the screen.